# DB2 Disable Constraints in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, constraints

In my table I have many check and foreignkey constraints.
In a stored procedure I copy mass data with litte changes on some columns.
So what I want to do is to disable these checks.

So as I assume I cannot disable the whole constraints, so what I want to do is to use informational constraints.

```
alter table MYTABLE
alter check CNSTR_CHECK_RANGE NOT ENFORCED;
```

The problem here is that I go to the whole contstraints and set it to not enforced.
After the stored procedure it should be enforced again.
It it the proper way to do this, can I say that i disable checks for a table only for the session?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a functionality in Db2.

Comment: Should I set the constraint enforced again after ending the copy in the stored procedure, or is this only temporary set for the stored procedure.
I need it after the stored procedure in the enforced mode again.

Comment: There is no such meaning as "temporary set for stored procedure" regarding a table constraint. Every `ALTER TABLE` affects the corresponding table disregarding of where it was issued from. You can't disable a constraint for some session, but have it enabled for others.